# How to deploy the progressive web app developed in ionic2 in live server

Tags: ionic2, progressive-web-apps

I have developed progressive web app using ionic 2 and I tested it on my local and it seems to work fine .

Now I want to deploy the PWA on my production server (Apache is already running ) where I will access it using some url … I did not found any article which would guide me to do so . If anybody knows the process please help me

Regards
Surjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this awesome video by JOSH
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVZ_HyA6XjA